# How to load the static files of django+nginx+gunicorn application using docker?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can't get my static files to come up. I've tried various settings and directory configurations and so on, but they just turn up as 404s.

Directory structure of application

```
.
├── config
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── local.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── aggre
│   ├── aggre
│   └── manage.py
|   └── static
├── requirements.txt
```

I have included static_url and root in settings.py and it looks like

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR),'static']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 'static')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/django/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/django/src
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/
COPY . /opt/services/django/src
RUN python aggre/manage.py collectstatic --no-input  # <-- here
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
EXPOSE 8000
ADD . /opt/services/django/src
CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "aggre", "--bind", ":8000", "aggre.wsgi:application"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/django/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/django/static/
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/opt/services/django/static/ 
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

local.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ***.***.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://djangoapp:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /opt/services/django/static;
    }
}
```

I am building and running using
**

> docker-compose up --built

Application is starting successfully but static files are not loading.
I am getting

> "/opt/services/django/src/static/js/bootstrap.js" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory)

**

Comment: I am not a Docker expert, but the error message has `/src/` in the path, but your `alias` statement does not.

Comment: thanks @RichardSmith. I tried but still i am not able to load static files.

Answer (score 0):

- in urls.py add

  ```
  from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
  ```

then append to urlpatterns like:

```
urlpatterns = [
YOUR_CONFIG 
] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

in Nginx config update like

```
location /static {
 root /opt/services/django; 
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'v update my comment about nginx config. Let's try again

Comment: Still i am getting  "/opt/services/django/static/js/bootstrap.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)